# angular.js: Set own variable in state?

Tags: angularjs

This is how I route to two different URL:

```
.state('cars', {
    url: "/cars/:title",
    templateUrl: 'templates/cars.html',
    controller: 'article',
})
.state('vegetables', {
    url: "/vegetables/:titel",
    templateUrl: 'templates/vegetables.html',
    controller: 'article',
})
```

The controller 'article' looks like this:

```
.controller('article', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "script.php",
        data: {'type': type, 'title': $stateParams.title},
    });
});
```

My question is how to set the variable type in the data of the controller? In this example type could be 'cars' or 'vegetables'. Can I set a variable in the state part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.controller('article', function($scope, $http, $stateParams,$state) {
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "script.php",
    data: {'type': $state.current.name, 'title': $stateParams.title},
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what router you are using or what version of Angular, but in Angular 1.2.x using the ui.router module (an addon), you would:

1) inject `$state` into your controller, then do something like this:

2) `$state.go('cars', {'title': 'an awesome car'})`

Comment: Yes, I'm using angular 1.2.2 and ui.router. Call me stupid, but I still don't get it. Can you please show me a code example as I want to set the variable type in the controller...?